# Getting componentStack error only in IE 11 in React js

Tags: reactjs

IE-11 - Getting ComponentStack Error while browsing through the tab buttons
On Other browsers its work fine
Here is the link
http://altislifereact.staging.wpengine.com/collections/

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please instead a link post your error in your scenario

Comment: Are you using local storage

Comment: Please include your errors directly in the question instead of linking to a website. You don't seem to have a Set polyfill. [You could include e.g. this one in your code](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-set).

Comment: Here is the Error i have receiving

componentStack "
    in div
    in t
    in t
    in t
    in main
    in t
    in t
    in withRouter(undefined)
    in div
    in t
    in t
    in t
    in withRouter(undefined)
    in t
    in t
    in t"

Comment: Hi  Tholle

Thanks for your Reply.
I have already implemented the following code
 
import "babel-polyfill";
import "isomorphic-fetch";

// Promise polyfills
require('es6-promise').polyfill()

Comment: Hi Avinash Mahlawat
I am not using Local storage